# htaccess rewrite for clean 2 get variables php

Tags: .htaccess

Please I have this url

http://sub.maydomaine.com/wallpapers.php?category=cities&name=San%20francisco

I want redirect to

http://sub.maydomaine.com/wallpapers/cities/San%20francisco

Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this rewrite rule, you should be able to support both urls:

```
RewriteRule ^wallpapers/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ wallpapers.php?category=$1&name=$2 [QSA]
```

Hope this helps.